# Add-ins missing in "New Outlook" for Outlook for Mac users

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

I work on an add-in for Microsoft Outlook, and some of our Outlook for Mac users have recently reported that they are unable to view any add-ins in the ribbon if they have the "New Outlook" toggle turned on.  The option "Get Add-ins" is accessible in a dropdown menu if they click the "..." option in the ribbon, but this "Get Add-ins" option is disabled.  Both the main inbox window and separate read/compose windows are affected.

I was able to replicate the issue in Outlook for Mac version 16.45 (21011103).

Is this expected behavior?  If not, is there a way to get add-ins to show in the ribbon again?

Thank you.

Comment: In the new Mac Outlook UI, add-ins appear in the overflow menu (appears on clicking ‘…’ button) on all surfaces along with a feature to pin the Add-in using Customise Toolbar option. 
On the Main Window, please ensure at least one mail item is selected in reading Pane for Add-ins to appear.  On all other windows, Add-ins should appear in the overflow Menu. Please verify the same.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to get add-ins to show in the main window and pop-out read window by restarting Outlook for Mac today, but I still can't see any add-ins or the "..." button to open the overflow window from the pop-out compose window. I've sent an email with the diagnostics ID and a screenshot of the issue to the email address you've provided.

Comment: This is expected behavior. Currently, Add-ins are not supported on the pop-out compose window yet. We have documented the unsupported features in New Mac Outlook here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/compare-outlook-add-in-support-in-outlook-for-mac#new-outlook-on-mac-preview

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information.

Comment: @SteveM, i've been looking for quality resources for developing a Microsoft Outlook (Mac) add-in. Struggling to find any decent resources.

Can you recommend any?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue.
My solution to get back the add-ins were the following.

- Go to [Outlook Preferences / Privacy]
- Mark  [Enable optional connected experiences]
- Restart Outlook

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was already enabled for me and did not fix the issue.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me and I found out the add-in I needed was already installed, just disabled by this setting

Answer (score 5):

Same problem for me. Add-ins where working on {old Outlook}, just not when I switched to the {new Outlook}. I fixed this by going to *system preferences* > *security & privacy* > *Privacy Tab (full disc Access)*. (Outlook was not even an option; I had to click the `+` icon and add it in.) The system then requested to restart Outlook and now all the add-ins are showing up.

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to the `Security & Privacy` setting on your mac.
It seems like you have to grant `Full Disk Access` to outlook in order to use some add-ins in the latest version.

Comment: Be careful, though. Doing this allows these plugins to do anything they want on the disk. Might be a risk.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed this a lot recently with outlook in regard to settings turned "on" as checked but not working - try the following which worked for me...

1. - Go to [Outlook Preferences / Privacy] - make sure to uncheck the box for "Enable optional connected experiences"
2. - Close window then close down outlook
3. - Open outlook go back to the same setting and check it back to "on" - close window then close down outlook
4. - Open outlook and hopefully zoom option is now back - go grab yourself a tea and enjoy the daily zoom grind again!

Expanded from Martin Reinholdt answer as my checkbox was already checked.

Answer (score 0):

I had to give full disk access to Outlook in order to use any add-ins.  As soon as I added full disk access, it is working as expected.