# Office 365 web add-in not showing on Outlook for Mac

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, macos-monterey

I am currently testing an Office 365 outlook add-in to make sure that it works on every browser and platform. The only issue is that I am unable to test it on the MacOS Office 365 application of outlook (new outlook) since the add-in won't show up. I followed multiple [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66016224/add-ins-missing-in-new-outlook-for-outlook-for-mac-users) that showed how to enable `Full Disk Access` and `Enable optional connected experience` so that the add-in would show up, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Just for some context, my add-in is an `ItemSend` add-in (it can't be deployed in the office store directly). Its deployed as `Admin-Managed` (using a link to my xml file) to all users and it won't show up in the Admin-Managed tab when clicking 'Get add-ins' button. Furthermore, it works fine on MacOS when I use the web application its only the MacOS Office 365 application of outlook (new outlook) that doesn't work. I also tried downloading the xml file and side loading it in the MacOS application, but every time the add-in gets added and when I close the 'Get add-ins' pop up it doesn't show up in the ribbon or when I re-open the 'Get add-ins' pop up. Also, I'm using the latest version of MacOS 12 (Monterey 12.7.2).

I was wondering if I'm missing a requirement or if ItemSend add-ins can't be added to MacOS directly?

**Edit:**
Here is my xml file.

```
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
        <Description resid="residAppDescription"/>
        <Requirements>
            <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
                <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
            </bt:Sets>
        </Requirements>
        <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
                <Runtimes>
                    <Runtime resid="residUILessFunctionFileUrl">
                        <Override type="javascript" resid="lauchEvent"/>
                    </Runtime>
                </Runtimes>
                <DesktopFormFactor>
                    ...
                </DesktopFormFactor>
            </Host>
        </Hosts>
        <Resources>
            ...
        </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
</VersionOverrides>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue can occur when the hosts section is not created correctly in manifest.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/host?view=common-js-preview#child-elements

As per documentation:
The values of child elements in the inner VersionOverrides override the values of the same-named elements in the parent VersionOverrides and the grandparent OfficeApp element.
Sample :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/xml-manifest-overview?tabs=tabid-3#manifest-v11-xml-file-examples-and-schemas

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've edited the post to show my xml file. Can you please tell me if I'm missing something?
Also I tried adding a `Name=Mailbox` to the `<Host>` element, but it made my xml not valid anymore